# How to check for return value from stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns a list of numbers in the case that the input id matches the table id. My question is, how do I check to see if the result being returned from the stored procedure isn't null? I just need to know if the returned value is 0(failed) or if the returned values are the numbers. Since I have a boolean variable that I want to set if there is valid data returned(not 0).

Here is my stored procedure:

```
      @InvestigatorID int
as
select DeleteTasks
from InvestigatorPermissionsTasks
where InvestigatorID = @InvestigatorID
```

Valid data returned looks like 
column name "exhibitID" value "123"/   column name "number" value "1-2-3-2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with your Filled DataTable

```
var adapter =  new SqlDataAdapter(YourCommand);
DataSet dataSet =  new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
YourTable = dataSet.Tables[0];    
if(YourTable != null)
{
   if(YourTable.Rows.Count > 0)
   { 

   }
}
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: the thing is I have a stored procedure doing this for me. I don't see why I have to put the command in myself?

Comment: YouCommand.CommandText ="Name of your stored procedure"; YouCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using an OUTPUT variable, you will get a recordset returned.  If there are no records in the recordset, the query "failed".  Otherwise, it was successful and matched at least one record.

Comment: how do I cehck it though to set my bool variable?